# How to check if billing address of customer is correct in stripe?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am trying a build a website for a client and I am using stripe for the first time. I build the platform and now I am checking payments using my card. I tried to enter wrong billing address but the payment still went through where as it should have been declined as the billing address is not correct.

I am trying to figure out how to setup a functionality in stripe that check whether the billing address is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To block cards that have incorrect billing details, you'd leverage Radar Rules: https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules#traditional-bank-checks that decline charges if there is a billing address check fail.

In test mode, you can mimic this by using the 4000000000000010 or `pm_card_avsFail` from the test cards: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses